# Running NUnit test depending on a condition

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, conditional-statements, target-platform

I'm writing a project using `Win7 x64`. Some part of my tests requires using SQLServer CE which only represents support for x86. I'm using `Visual Studio 2010 Express` and I gotta change platform target for my projects manually editing *.cproj files to run, for example, `schema export test (NHibernate)`. Howcome I run a part of my tests depending on a platform target.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a built-in mechanism in NUnit to handle this scenario, but at the very least you can use preprocessor directives.

For instance, create a "Debug x86" solution configuration, targeting x86. Then define the DEBUG_X86 conditional compilation symbol (in the properties of the project). Finally, surround your unit test with preprocessor directives:

```
#if DEBUG_X86
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    // This test will only run when compiled with Debug x86
}
#endif
```

**Edit**: Actually, you don't even have to create a new solution configuration, as it's possible to define the conditional symbols depending on the platform (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313450/869621). So define a WIN32 compilation symbol, and surround your test with it:

```
#if WIN32
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    // This test will only run when compiled for x86
}
#endif
```