# Reference Shell32.dll and compile as x64?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

I need to get file properties (specifically 'Product Version'), for which I'm using Shell32. It works fine in x86, but when I try to compile as x64 I get the following error:

> A single valid machine type compatible with the input type library must be specified.

I am guessing it's because I'm using 32-bit visual studio to compile. I can't use AnyCPU instead of x64.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change C# DllImport target code depending on x64/x86](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934570/change-c-sharp-dllimport-target-code-depending-on-x64-x86)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably referencing the x86 `Shell32`. On a x64 machine, you can find the x86 `Shell32` in `%windir%\SysWOW64` and the x64 version in `%windir%\System32`.
There's a great little page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that may help.

Comment: I did try that, but the reference always switches to the x86 version (based on the interop info in the registry I assume).