# Creating single winform setup to run both on 32 bit and 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, dll, operating-system

I want to create single window application setup that can be installed both on 32 bit as well as on 64 bit machine. I have few dlls that can be used according to DLL version only i.e. A.dll(32bit), A.dll(64bit).

If software is being installed on 32 bit machine, all 32bit dlls should be used otherwise other.

Now I can create two different setups by building project twice. However I want to have just one setup that will take care automatically.

I have gone through [this](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/mixed-32-64-wizard.html) link which seems to be what I am looking for however it's based on the product they are selling not default windows setup creation wizard.

I found a duplicate question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102371/how-to-implement-conditional-compilation-ti-run-application-on-32-bit-and-64-bit) with no answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11936113/17034

Answer (score 1):

add dll import code

```
[DllImport("MyDll32.dll", EntryPoint = "Func1", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int Func1_32(int var1, int var2);

[DllImport("MyDll64.dll", EntryPoint = "Func1", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int Func1_64(int var1, int var2);

public static int Func1(int var1, int var2) {
    return IntPtr.Size == 8 /* 64bit */ ? Func1_64(var1, var2) : Func1_32(var1, var2);
}
```

solution explorer --> Double click Properties (A new tab should open up) --> build tab

Setting configurations--->options( Any CPU, x32bit, x64bit)---> to 'Any CPU' ensures that your application will work on both 32 and 64bit computers.

[image]

Comment: I have few native and unmanaged dlls that need to be referenced as per installation. Doing so is not picking right set of dlls and i cannot copy them in same folder as they have same name.

Comment: see this documentation 64 bit work on 32 bit OS http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/support/documentation/dotnet/n_distribute_configure.htm

Comment: My 64bit Dll are not working on 32 bit OS. I have unmanaged dlls provided with SDK.

Comment: I don't have control over unmanaged code, it has been called from a wrapper provided by SDK.