# C# - Visual Studio - 32 and 64 bit DLLs in separated output folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I have an c# application and I want to have 32 and 64 bit versions of it. I use InnoSetup to create installer and both 32 and 64 bit exes are in the same folder. In my project I need to reference dll which has 32 and 64 bit version and place it in separate output folders(x86/x64). Is it possible to make it using Visual Studio?

Comment: It is not obvious why you created two separate EXE files, your user has no real idea which one is "best".  Having a dependency on an unmanaged DLL that demands a specific process bitness is however pretty common, simply tell the OS where to look for the file.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11936113/17034  Use a post-build event to create the subdirectories and copy the files.

Answer (score -1):

1.) Open "Configuration Manager":

[image: Configuration Manager]

2.) Create a new configuration by selecting "<New...>":

[image]

3.) Give it a name and copy settings from an existing configuration:

[image]

4.) Select the platform or add it ("<New...>")

[image]

5.) Copy settings from an existing platform:

[image]

Now you can change project settings for each confiuration, simply change the path in the "Build" tab.