# Reference for .NET-Application has different files for x86 and x64 - how load the correct version at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, anycpu

I use TAPIEx.Net in my application to connect to a TAPI-Driver.
I compile my Application as AnyCPU. TAPIEx.Net has a x86 Version (TAPIEx.net.dll) and a x64 Version (TAPIex.net.x64.dll). For developing, I reference TAPIEx.net.x64.dll (because I develop in x64 Environment). But I am searching for the solution what I have to do, when a customer loads the application in 32bit-Environment?

Comment: Don't use AnyCPU. Explicitly build 32-bit and 64-bit versions of your app that include the correct library. Each user can then download the one they want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934570/change-c-sharp-dllimport-target-code-depending-on-x64-x86/11936113#11936113