# How do you include Microsoft.Interop.Excel version 11 when on WinXP and version 12 when on Win7?

Tags: c#, dll, preprocessor-directive

I understand that preprocessor directives are appropriate here, based on this question:
[Preprocessor directive in C# for importing based on platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313402/preprocessor-directive-c)

A simple copy paste of

```
#if WIN64
    [DllImport("ZLIB64.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
#else
    [DllImport("ZLIB32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
#endif
```

at the beginning of my namespace didn't work because Visual Studio is complaining that

> Attribute 'DLLImport' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on the 'method' declarations

However, changing the `#else` line to `#elif WIN32` got it to compile.

How would I apply that technique of loading different DLLs based on the operating system to this specific case of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` for version 11 vs version 12?

Comment: Probably you have to do it not during compilation time but during runtime. .NET 4 has the `dynamic` keyword. In previous versions I successfully used Reflection to call methods of Office COM classes.

Comment: Preprocessor directives come into play when you _build_ a solution, not when you _deploy_ a solution, so I don't know that they will do what you expect.

Comment: Sounds like you're got the DllImport in the wrong spot.  It probably builds when you add `#elif WIN32` because NEITHER of those constants are defined so it doesn't add the code at all.

Comment: @UweKeim this is running on .NET 3.5

Comment: @DStanley what would cover the case of deploying? VS won't let me publish if there are build errors, and I'm on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to link to one particular version at compile time (as you sample suggests) - you need to have 2 projects that will include different versions of Interop assembly and refer to the same set of source files.

If you want to do it at run-time and use strongly typed objects you'd need to wrap methods that are interesting to you and expose them through your custom classes/interfaces because interop assemblies do not share any base classes (siblings instead of 11 is parent of 12 as you may wish).