# Adding pdfium.dll to visual studio

Tags: c#, pdfium

For the application that I am making, I need to make use of the Pdfiumviewer package, which in turn requires you to add Pdfium itself, which is made available by Google. There is a "tutorial" on how to add pdfium on the official site but I haven't been able to decipher what exactly it is that I need to do.

At first glance, it appeared that you can get Pdfium via de Nuget Package Manager but it quickly became apparent that nuget doesn't add the actual dll to the project, and simply adding it as a reference doesn't work either. (throws 'reference could not be added' error).
After this, I attempted to move the Pdfium dll to the bin/debug folder, but that still gives the same error. After doing some research, I found out that this dll is not supported by visual studio and you have to build/integrate it using the command line.

There are instructions on how to achieve this provided on
https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/
https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer/wiki/Building-PDFium

but after a few days of reading into it, I still have no clue what exactly I should and shouldn't do in the tutorial provided by google.

Therefor, I would like to kindly ask if anyone is either able to explain in plain English how to run through these steps, or if anyone knows a more user friendly tutorial to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using Winforms?

To get the *pdfRenderer* control in a WinForm: Add the `PdfiumViewer` NuGet package to the project; open the projects packages folder in Windows Explorer and drag the `PdfiumViewer.dll` file onto the `Toolbox` window; A control called `PdfRenderer` will be available to add:

[image: Adding PdfRenderer control to WinForms]

Comment: For me to get this to work on winforms, I had to install the packages https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfiumViewer.Native.x86_64.v8-xfa/ and https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfiumViewer.Native.x86.v8-xfa/ and then copy the /bin/debug/x86 and /bin/debug/x64 folders to the root folder, as per the discussion here: https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer/issues/83

Answer (score 25):

In case anyone still needs help with this, I was having the same problem and solved it using [@Jack 's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646556/adding-pdfium-dll-to-visual-studio/67373337#comment110360344_56054504) on [@Paddy 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56054504/11417475):

1. Install `PdfiumViewer` NuGet package
2. Install `PdfiumViewer.Native.x86.v8-xfa` NuGet package
3. Install `PdfiumViewer.Native.x86_64.v8-xfa` NuGet package

After installing all 3 packages, I published the application (my application is ClickOnce) and executed it, and it worked just fine!

Comment: [Combined with Ralfs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43046814/591285), this was the only thing that worked for me. These two additional packages will add `x86` and `x64` folders each with their own `pdfium.dll`. Now we can just use Ralfs solution to load the proper library.

Comment: I had to install "PdfiumViewer.Native.x86.v8-xfa" and 64-bit NuGet packages on the startup project; then it worked great. When installed on a referenced project it won't copy pdfium.dll to the output folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.
In my case i was working on a project for a client that would run the application with an IIS identity user.

After installing the packages above (PdfiumViewer,PdfiumViewer.Native.x86.v8-xfa ,PdfiumViewer.Native.x86_64.v8-xfa), it still didn't work.

After all the problem was due to lack of permissons of this user (it needs write, modify permissons). Just to let you know another use case that led to the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I had installed a Nuget package just before receiving this message.  It turned out that the missing Pdfium dll was hidden deep in my project's packages folder, but for some reason it didn't get copied to the project's bin folder.  After finding the right version (x64) in the folder tree and copying it into the bin folder, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I had tremendous grief with this missing dll, until I found the easiest way I found was to go to Nuget Package Manager and install the PDFium.Windows package.